# console.log() prints out function

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I am doing an new project in CoffeeScript and Rails, but I stuck at something, when I am coding up some classes in CoffeeScript.

I am doing the following things:

```
# Definition of functions like every, after here...

class Tracker
  constructor: ->
    @currentTime = 0
    @_updateTime(@currentTime)
    every 1000, @_countTime.bind @ # Just a shorthand for setInterval

  _countTime: ->
    time = @currentTime + 1
    @_updateTime(time)

  _updateTime: (time) ->
    @currentTime = time
    @_formatTime

  _formatTime: ->
    t = @currentTime

    seconds = t % 60
    minutes = (t / 60) % 60
    hours = t / 3600

    return seconds + minutes + hours
```

But when I am printing out (using `console.log`)the return-value of the function `_formatTime` I am getting the function printed out.
I googled but didn't find anything useful. Checked the IRC of #coffeescript, too, but no response there.

Would be glad to have anything helpful here.

Comment: try adding parenthesis at the end of _formatTime. if you are just console.log _formatTime you are printing a variable that contains a function and not running the function `_formatTime()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coffescript compiles to JavaScript, so in the browser you can't use the nice Coffeescript syntax.  What you are calling `_formatTime` without parentheses, you will get the definition of the function.  To get what you are looking for you would need to call it as `_formatTime()`